# Searching and replacing all occurrence of a string in a char array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, search, replace, char

I have a char array and I want to find all the positions of a specific substring and then I will replace all the substring with something different.

for example:

```
char [35] = "the boy stole the cup from the table.";
```

1. I want to print out every position where `"the"` is. I have found some functions like `find` but it only finds the first position of what I want. I tried using a loop but that did not also work out.

2. I also want to replace all occurence of `"the"` with something like `"that"`
   can someone show me how to achieve this. And I am working specifically with the char array and not string class.

Comment: [strstr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) gives you the start of the first match (as a char pointer); if you then start to search at least one character after that you'll get a second match, if any. As for the algorithm, you just copy the part before the first match, append the replacement string, skip the search string, and match again. If you could show us some code and where specifically you're stuck?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: `I have found some functions like find but it only finds the first position of what I want. I tried using a loop but that did not also work out.` Then you're using `find` incorrectly, as that is exactly how you would solve this. Post your code.

Comment: That sentence contains 38 characters. How are you going to store 38 characters in a char[35] exactly? What's more, if you replace "the" with "that" it's now 41 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function . i think it will work.

```
void find_and_replace(string& source, string const& find, string const& replace)
{
    for(string::size_type i = 0; (i = source.find(find, i)) != string::npos;)
    {
        source.replace(i, find.length(), replace);
        i += replace.length();
    }
}


   content = "this is c++ programming";

   find_and_replace(content, "c++", "java");
```

Comment: Store `replace.length()` in a variable before the `for` loop to avoid possibly calling the function multiple times (for performance). Same with `find.length()`.